# Information from un-normalized table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that is a combination of a customer table and an orders table. It looks something like this:

```
_______________________________________________________
| Id | Cust Id  | Other Id | Date | Has Prod 1 | Has Prod 2 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |          | 1        | 2009 | False      | True       |
| 2  | 1        |          | 2008 | False      | True       |
| 3  | 2        |          | 2008 | True       | False      |
| 4  | 1        |          | 2009 | True       | True       |
| 5  | 2        |          | 2009 | False      | False      |
| 6  | 1        |          | 2010 | False      | True       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The only way I know if I have a customer is to find a customer Id in the Cust Id column. The Cust Id and Other Id point to other tables which are irrelevant to this discussion.

I would like to do 2 things:

I would like to produce a report or table that summarizes the customers and performs a logical “or” of the “Has” columns, such as this:

```
_________________________________________________
| Id | Cust Id  | Other Id | Has Prod 1 | Has Prod 2 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1        |          | True       | True       |
| 2  | 2        |          | True       | False      |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to obtain the latest row within each Cust Id group, such as this:

```
_______________________________________________________
| Id | Cust Id  | Other Id | Date | Has Prod 1 | Has Prod 2 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 2        |          | 2009 | False      | False      |
| 6  | 1        |          | 2010 | False      | True       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance.
GRB

Comment: What have you tried so far? And are you using SQL or Access's Query-By-Example?

Comment: The Access QBE uses SQL, so @rajah9's question makes no sense at all.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, Some Access users never write a line of SQL and only use the QBE GUI. (The diagram above suggests OP may be a QBE user.) I was trying to establish whether the OP was familiar only with QBE or instead could understand an SQL solution. And I wouldn't say the Access QBE "uses SQL" so much as it is an interface to generate SQL.

Comment: All Access users write SQL -- they just don't necessarily do it by hand. If you're using Access, you're using SQL, so your question just doesn't make any sense. If you want to ask if they are using the QBE, then just ask that question, instead of using misleading terminology that implies things that aren't true.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Cust ID], MIN([Has Prod 1]) AS MinOne, MIN([Has Prod 2]) AS MinTwo
FROM customerorder
GROUP BY [Cust ID]
```

MIN() returns the smallest value. -1 is True and 0 is False, so if one record of the grouped rows is True, -1 is returned.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM customerorder AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT [Cust ID], Max([Date]) As MaxDate
            FROM customerorder 
            GROUP BY [Cust ID]) AS t2
ON ([t1].[Cust ID] = [t2].[Cust ID] AND [t1].[Date] = [t2].[MaxDate])
```

If the last row is determined by Max([Date]), as is indicated by your sample data, the above query will return the last row for every customer.

Comment: cularis, thank you very much for your timely answer. Looks like these will give me what I need. GRB

Comment: @GRB Welcome to SO! Have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). You can upvote useful or even accept them.